# Can I use `wilcox_test()` to compar multiple means without `friedman_test()`?

Tags: mean, wilcoxon-mann-whitney-test, wilcoxon-signed-rank, friedman-test

In [this example](https://www.datanovia.com/en/lessons/friedman-test-in-r/),use `friedman_test()` first to find `significant difference between group`,and then use `wilcox_test()` to identify which groups are different.
Similarly, use `pairwise paired t-tests` as posthoc test after `repeated-measures ANOVA`.

How about use `wilcox_test()` directly? If `p.adj` of each cell >0.05,we know `equal mean`.Otherwise if any `p.adj`<0.05,we know `mean not equal between group`.

Do I need to `friedman_test()` first when I compare meanmultiple means?

Answer (score 1):

Not a full fledged answer, but nevertheless some hints.

1. You never know "equal mean". You just do not reject it.
2. In principle, you can directly look at adjusted pairwise tests. They will, however have lower power than the global test. Why? Because the global test is also able to detect if e.g. groups 1 and 2 are different from groups 3 and 4, a comparison that is not being made with pairwise tests.
3. Since the Friedman test is a generalization of the sign test to multiple groups, it is inconsequental to use Wilcoxon's approach for the pairwise comparison. The generalization of the signed-rank test to more than two groups is the Quade test, e.g. available in [R](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/stats/html/quade.test.html).

Comment: Is `friedman_test()` able to detect `(group1 and group2) vs (group3 and group4)` ?

Comment: Yes, so would it look for (group1 and group3) versus (group2 and group4) etc. I'd say this is the whole point of using global tests.